# Getting time to first byte (TTFB) in twisted and scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted.web

I'm trying to get **time to first byte** (TTFB) in scrapy. I know that there is a `download_latency` property in meta but it includes download time as I understand.
Download_latency is calculated in addCallback function here: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L323. As I see I should calculate time within the request but I don't know how to do it. I'm not even sure it's possible.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by TTFB? The time to get the HTTP status after the request bytes have all been sent?

Comment: What's wrong on including download time? From what I understand, `download_latency` measures time between sending request and getting the response, which should be exactly what TTFB is.

Comment: @paultrmbrth I think he means the time elapsed between the start of the request and the first byte he recieves from the server

Comment: Yes, @BLANQUERAdrien is right. This is time between the start of request and the first byte. Here is the description in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte.

Comment: I'm trying to use scrapy as SEO audit tool to understand which webpage needs optimization on server side. Download_latency includes time for downloading content. Because of that download_latency might be much bigger that time to first byte (TTFB). As recommended TTFB is near 200ms then even small inaccuracy in measurement gives wrong result.